# How to POST JSON data to server using AJAX jQuery

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ajax

### Keep getting error when trying to post 'order' JSON data to JSON file on Node.js server

GET request works fine but 'Error' function executes instead of the 'success' function when trying to do a POST request. Am I missing anything? Do I need to use php?

The dev tools console shows the following error message:

`POST http://.../orders.json 405 (Method Not Allowed) jquery.js:10109`

```
$("#add-order").on("click", function()
{
    var order = 
    {
        name: $name.val(),
        food: $food.val()
    };

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "orders.json",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(order),
        processData: false,
        success: function(newOrder)
        {
            alert("success");
            $orders.append("<li>Name: " + newOrder.name +", food: " + newOrder.food + "</li>");
        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert("Error posting order");
        }

    });
});
```

### Node js server

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer(function(request, response)
{
    response.writeHead(200, { "Conent-Type": "text/json" })
    fs.readFile("orders.json", function(error, data)
    {
        if (error)
        {
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write("Error: File Not Found");
        } 
        else response.write(data);
        response.end();
    })

});

server.listen(port, function(error)
{
    if (error) console.log("Something went wrong. Error: ", error);
    else console.log("server is listening to port " + port);
})
```

Comment: Well, *what* error are you getting?

Comment: No, PHP won't solve whatever problem you have.

Comment: @Bergi Sorry for not clarifying. I was referring to the 'error' function I set up inside the AJAX object. When trying to post JSON data the 'error' function executes instead of the 'success' function

Comment: The onerror callback gets passed an error as its argument - log that: `error: function(err) { console.error('posting order', err); }`. Also check your devtools console in general what messages there are.

Comment: @Bergi I have provided the dev tools console error message

Comment: Typo: `"Conent-Type"` should be `"Content-Type"`

Answer (score -1):

```js
var http = require('http');
var requestListener = function(req, res) {
  console.log("" + req.method)
  if (req.method === "POST") {

    let data = '';
    req.on('data', chunk => {
      data += chunk;
    })
    req.on('end', () => {
      console.log(data)
      res.end("received");
    })

  }
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('Hello, World!' + req.method);
}

var server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Listening on port 3000")
});








//curl -d '{"name":"1","age":"2"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' localhost:3000

//Output

/*
Listening on port 3000
POST
undefined
{"name":"1","age":"2"}
*/
```

Or you can explore express or any other middle ware for easy parsing and handling.

Comment: The above code was tried and tested at https://www.katacoda.com/courses/nodejs/playground

Comment: What was the problem? What did you change and why? How did that fix it? Please post an explanation, not just code.

Comment: @Bergi The if (req.method === "POST")  was not handled properly it is self explanatory.